# How to backup stored procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, backup

I use `mysqldump` with MySQL 5.0 and I back it up every day, but do not understand the method that only stored procedure backs up.

How can I back it up?

Answer (score 47):

I'm not sure whether you're asking to back up stored procedures as well as everything else, or just the stored procedures on their own...

Stored procedured in dump with everything else:

```
mysqldump -R <dbname> #or
mysqldump --routines <dbname>
```

Just the stored procedures:

```
mysqldump -n -t -d -R <dbname> #or
mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data --routines <dbname>
```

Does that help?

Comment: In my version of mysqldump (mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.1.69, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)), at least, that should be -R, not -r.  From the doc: -R, --routines      Dump stored routines (functions and procedures). -r, --result-file=name Direct output to a given file. This option should be used in MSDOS, because it prevents new line '\n' from being converted to '\r\n' (carriage return + line feed).

Comment: @davej Good point - I guess I missed that somehow. (I would like to think I tested it, but I guess not...) Thanks for the note.

Comment: DOS>mysqldump -uroot -p -n -t -d -R test > test_procs.sql

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump - u dbusername (ex: -uroot) -ppassword (ex:-pmysql@dbpas) --routines <dbname>
```

use the username and password could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put `routines=true` in the `[mysqldump]` section of your `my.cnf` file (you may have to add this section as it is not usually present in a virgin `my.cnf` file) to include routines in a normal dump.