# How to export stored procedure from local machine and Import into server?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a dozen stored procedure written in my local phpmyadmin. I want to export it to my server along with the tables. Is there any way to do this?. Please help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not quite an answer but may provide some useful details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115573/how-do-i-view-my-stored-procedures-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in phpmyadmin  while you are exporting database 
choose custom
and then tick the add `procedures/events/triggers` option

or

use the below command

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name --routines --events --triggers > file.sql
```

for more info visit this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQLDump to export your stored proc :

Stored procedured in dump with everything else:

```
mysqldump -r <dbname> #or
mysqldump --routines <dbname>
```

Just the stored procedures:

```
mysqldump -n -t -d -r <dbname> #or
mysqldump --no-create-db --no-create-info --no-data --routines <dbname>
```

From : [How to backup stored procedures in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881223/how-to-backup-stored-procedures-in-mysql)